# What causes " Expected /\/\/ Type definitions for (non-npm package )?/" on DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: definitelytyped

I am trying to add a set of typescript  type definitions written by another author.
I have cleaned up all the DANGER warnings but I am still getting this:

'''

clean data

Clean logs

Clean output

Using local Definitely Typed at /home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.

Parsing definitions...

Found 6792 packages.

Parsing in parallel...

Error: At 1:1 : Expected /// Type definitions for (non-npm package )?/

```
at Object.parseHeaderOrFail (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/definitelytyped-header-parser/index.js:77:15)

at combineDataForAllTypesVersions (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/lib/definition-parser.js:95:160)

at Object.getTypingInfo (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/lib/definition-parser.js:27:82)

at util_1.logUncaughtErrors (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/lib/definition-parser-worker.js:17:50)

at Object.logUncaughtErrors (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/util/util.js:78:38)

at process.on.message (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/lib/definition-parser-worker.js:15:16)

at process.emit (events.js:198:13)

at emit (internal/child_process.js:832:12)

at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Error: Parsing failed.

```
at fail (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/util/util.js:272:20)

at ChildProcess.child.on (/home/travis/build/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node_modules/types-publisher/bin/util/util.js:261:21)

at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)

at finish (internal/child_process.js:817:14)

at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm [0mERR! errno 1

npm ERR! definitely-typed@0.0.3 test: `node node_modules/types-publisher/bin/tester/test.js --run-from-definitely-typed`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the definitely-typed@0.0.3 test script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/travis/.npm/_logs/2020-05-23T23_58_11_605Z-debug.log

The command "npm run test" exited with 1.
'''

Answer (score 0):

Type definitions require header, see more at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library

**TLDR**

Prepend something like this (adapt to appropriate package name etc.):

```
// Type definitions for Node.js 10.12
// Project: https://nodejs.org/
// Definitions by: Microsoft TypeScript <https://github.com/Microsoft>
//                 Definitely Typed <https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped>
//                 Alberto Schiabel <https://github.com/jkomyno>
```